# Python: import requests gets a lot errors MacOS

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, python-requests

New to programming and followed this course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F2m91eKmts&feature=emb_logo

When things went to Webscraping, got errors:

Code says:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.05349000000007&lon=-118.24531999999999')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

Return is:

> File "/Users/.../python/cleverprogrammer/webscraping.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import requests   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/**init**.py",
>   line 112, in 
>       from . import utils   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/utils.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       from ._internal_utils import to_native_string   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/_internal_utils.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/compat.py",
>   line 59, in 
>       from http import cookiejar as cookielib   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/cookiejar.py",
>   line 39, in 
>       from calendar import timegm ImportError: cannot import name 'timegm' from 'calendar'
>   (/Users/.../python/cleverprogrammer/calendar.py)

Is there some problem with the way Requests are installed? Maybe use of `pipenv` is not the correct way?
And why does it call for `calendar.py` file and `'timegm'`? `Calendar.py` is different file from the same course, in same folder.

What are the steps, that I can take, to get rid of these messages and get working Requests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have your own local file named `calendar.py` that is interfering with the standard Python module of the same name.  Rename your file, or adjust your `PYTHONPATH` so that the local version of `calendar.py` isn't on it.

Comment: Damn, that was easy. Changed calendar.py name and code works. And I already thought that i messed up my Mac. :) thanks a lot.

Comment: The message tells you which file is used: `(/Users/.../python/cleverprogrammer/calendar.py)`

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: No. I am familiar with concept of venv, but haven't yet learned how to do apply them to my work. I'll need to figure out, how to set my vscode built in terminal to use that venv for every project. From your point of view, is it ok not to work in venv while learning or you should always use them?

Comment: Always use a virtual environment. Quick-and-dirty instructions I wrote up can be found at https://snarky.ca/a-quick-and-dirty-guide-on-how-to-install-packages-for-python/.

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting any errors when trying out your code. It looks infallible. I suggest that you check what module of python you are working with, and consider updating to python 3.0+ if possible.

Try this

```
import calendar
print calendar.__file__
```

It will show you the module it's lodaing.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/calendar.pyc
```

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, but a great suggestion.